# How to COMPLETELY destroy ALL sessionS stored?

Tags: php

I store these sessions for logged-in users by a piece of code below:

```
$_SESSION = $r-> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

// Store the HTTP_USER_AGENT:
$_SESSION['agent'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Then I print them out:

```
Array ( [user_id] => 1 [username] => asdfxc [user_level] => 0 [agent] => d30847a2ec9c978a0e4db5470b78b327 [lid] => 1 )
```

What I want is to destroy them ALL in my `logout.php` page, which i code like this:

```
   // If no first_name session variable exists, redirect the user:
if (!isset($_SESSION['agent']) OR ($_SESSION['agent'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) ) {

$url = BASE_URL . 'index.php'; // Define the URL.
ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
header("Location: $url");
exit(); // Quit the script.

} else { // Log out the user.

$_SESSION = array(); // Destroy the variables.
session_unset();// remove all session variables
session_destroy(); // Destroy the session itself.
setcookie (session_name(), '', time()-3600); // Destroy the cookie.

}

// Print a customized message:
echo '<p>You are now logged out.</p>';
```

The problem is that when i tested by logging in as the **first** user ID on Firefox, then logging it out, then logging it in as the **second** user ID, the sessions of the **first** user ID has been still stored.

I then tried open Google Chrome, logging in as the *second** user ID, the session of the **first** user was till there!

Can you help me to COMPLETELY delete/destroy them ALL in my `logout.php` page, please?

Thanks!

**EDIT** as per @Dagon's request:

*1/ Store the session of a particular logged-in user:*

```
$q = "SELECT user_id, username, user_level 
              FROM users";

        $r = $mysqli->query($q);

        /*Fetch the results into variables.
        The query will return an array with three elements—one indexed at user_id, one at
        username, and the third at user_level,
        all three can be fetched right into $_SESSION, 
        resulting in $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], and
        $_SESSION['user_level'] */

         $_SESSION = $r-> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

        // Store the HTTP_USER_AGENT:
        $_SESSION['agent'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        //Redirect to the item page (index.php)
header('Location: .../to/home.php');
exit();
```

*2/ Populate it in the `home.php` page*

```
if (isset($_SESSION['agent'])) {

echo 'Welcome:'.$_SESSION['username'].'!';

}
```

Comment: how do you know the session is still there? what do you mean ny "ogging it in as the second user ID, the sessions of the first user ID has been still stored."

Comment: I know by viewing the `username`. The `username` of the **first** user ID is still always echo'ed out when I try doing the `print_r($_SESSION);` for the 2nd user id, while testing. Also, I added the conditional of `if (isset($_SESSION['agent'])) { echo Welcome:'.$_SESSION['username'].'!';}` in the `index.php` page as the logged-in user is directed to. The same `array (keys=<values)` and the same username are shown up for the different logged-in user IDs.

Comment: sounds like an issue  with how your populating the sessions. sessions are user unique, so your just always populating the 1st id

Comment: So is there anything wrong with my codes- the ways I store and destroy the sessions? and what should I do to correct it? can you help give an answer away, indeed? who knows your answer also help the community!

Comment: you dont show how you populate the session as a particular user

Comment: please see the **EDIT** section, thanks!

Comment: `SELECT user_id, username, user_level 
              FROM users` so every one is the same? with out a `WHERE=` everyone will have the same id

Comment: @Dagon: you are the best!

Comment: let me turn this in to an answer for all those feel good "points"

Answer (score 0):

the issue is your giving every one the same id as your query is not selecting a particular user.

```
SELECT user_id, username, user_level FROM users
```

should have a `WHERE` clause to identify the user you want